# Unable to subscribe to CDC events in Sandbox

Tags: platform-event, change-data-capture

With the example given in the link:
[Trailhead - Subscribe to Events](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/change-data-capture/subscribe-to-events), I was able to successfullt connect to my DEV org and listen to the change events for both custom and standard objects.

However when I try the same for my sandbox, I get a message saying that the subscription is successful, however the output JSON is not being displayed.

I use the below command to connect to my sandbox:

```
$ java -classpath target/emp-connector-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-phat.jar com.salesforce.emp.connector.example.DevLoginExample <login_URL> <username> <password> <channel>
```

and the output I get is:

> > > >
> > >       SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> > >       SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
> > >       SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
> > >       [2019-09-25 06:32:04.475] Success:[/meta/handshake]
> > >       {ext={replay=true, payload.format=true}, minimumVersion=1.0, clientId=yax3praacplr5nhx, supportedConnectionTypes=[Ljava.lang.Object;@348872, channel=/meta/handshake, id=1, version=1.0, successful=true}
> > >       <<<<
> > >       >
> > >       Subscribed: Subscription [/data/ContactChangeEvent:-2]
> > >       [2019-09-25 06:32:05.116] Success:[/meta/subscribe]
> > >       {clientId=yax3praacplr5nhx, channel=/meta/subscribe, id=2, subscription=/data/ContactChangeEvent, successful=true}
> > >       <<<<
> > >       >
> > >       [2019-09-25 06:32:08.795] Success:[/meta/connect]
> > >       {clientId=yax3praacplr5nhx, advice={reconnect=retry, interval=0, timeout=110000}, channel=/meta/connect, id=3, successful=true}
> > >       <<<<

I can see that the subscription seems to be successful, but when I change any Contact, I do not see the JSON response as I was expecting.

Comment: Same Issue here - I set up `Change Data Capture` with `Account (Account)`. All logs show I successfully subscribed to `/data/AccountChangeEvent`. Permissions should be ok - the User used to log in is an Admin user and can see and edit accounts. When I edit the name of an account I expect a CDC event. My CometD does not show any event activity for my subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution may be related to encryption.
I had a simmilar Issue and opened a ticket with salesforce.

This was the response:

> Based on the case description i see that , you unable to get the
>   details when you subscribe to change data event. I see that this is
>   because in you org encryption in enabled. When ever encryption is
>   enabled first you need to create an event bus from "Key Management".
>   After you create an Event Bus you need to enable the perm  in
>   "Encryption Policy" > "Select Encrypt and deliver Change Data Capture
>   events."  Then you will receive the messages. For more information i
>   suggest you to check below articles.

[cdc_security_shield_encryption](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_security_shield_encryption.htm)

[cdc_security_shield_create_secret](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_security_shield_create_secret.htm)

[cdc_security_shield_enable_delivery](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_security_shield_enable_delivery.htm)

Comment: Thank you - that was it!